# Why does operator+ not exist for std::string and std::string_view?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

Why does an overloaded [`operator+`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) not exist for `std::string` and `std::string_view`? Like:

```cpp
// Omitting template parameters
std::basic_string operator+(const std::basic_string& lhs, const StringViewLike& rhs);
std::basic_string operator+(const StringViewLike& lhs, const std::basic_string& rhs);
```

They are missing, therefore such forced code is not optimal, it performs an extra copy:

```cpp
std::string make_phrase(std::string_view say, std::string_view to) {
  return std::string(say) + std::string(to);
}
```

It allocates a temporary string for `to`, copies the view data, appends the new data (aka copies it) to the result and then destroys the temporary string.

The member [`operator+=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D) surprisingly has the overloaded version:

```cpp
basic_string& operator+=(const StringViewLike& t);
```

That sometimes helps to solve the issue above, but the solution does not look well readable:

```cpp
return std::string(say) += to;
```

Comment: It looks like [this has been proposed](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2591r0.html).

Comment: Nice proposal, we may see it in C++26.

Comment: @NathanOliver Perhaps yes, I could not find it. The accepted answer there is irrelevant, is about some string ref.